# Text box with long character such as URL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have text boxes that are getting URL inside, when you put the URL (long) in it, I want it to go down one row in order to see the last character of the URL.
How can I achieve it instead 
of changing the width size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBlock` class features the [`TextBlock.TextTrimming` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which enables users to add an ellipsis (...) at the end of text that is too long to be displayed in the `TextBlock`. If your `TextBox` is *not* being used for text input, then you can simply use a `TextBlock` control instead.

If you really need to use a `TextBox`, then unfortunately that has no such property. One alternative is to use a custom `TextBox` that does have this property. You can find an example of that in the [WPF TextBox With Ellipsis](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/309927/WPF-TextBox-With-Ellipsis) page on CodeProject.

---

UPDATE >>>

As you have not shown any code, nobody can tell you what you did wrong. Either way, this is a simple issue that *I'm sure* that you can fix yourself. Add this to a different view somewhere else:

```
<TextBlock Text="123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" 
    Width="100" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
```

Now you should be able to see the ellipsis at the end of the `TextBlock`. That's how simple it is. If you example is not working, then *you* have made it not work by adding something else.

Comment: HI Shirdan,Thank you ,I have tried to change the text box to text box like suggested and I see it in the VS designer but when I run it Im not able to see it,what can be the problem?

Comment: What I did is just change the name in the TAG from <TextBox /> to <TextBlock />

Answer (score 1):

Try scrolling the text box to the beginning of the text when focus lost (not sure how to do that with data binding):

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).ScrollToHome();
}
```

You can also create a Behavior to avoid direct event handling:

Add reference to System.Windows.Interactivity (installed with Expression Blend).

Add a Behavior class:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class AutoScrollToHomeBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.LostFocus += (tb, args) =>
                {
                    (tb as TextBox).ScrollToHome();
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Attach a Behavior to your text box:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"  Width="120">
                <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:AutoScrollToHomeBehavior />
                </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"  Width="120">
                <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:AutoScrollToHomeBehavior />
                </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: HI PashaPash ,I use MVVM and not direct event,there is a way to do that?

Comment: CaretPosition is not a dependency property, so you will need a custom Behavior for text box to handle focus lost. See my edit.